# Where to save INI file in ASP.NET web service application

Tags: asp.net, web-services, ini

I have written a web service application, in that I have created an INI file in order to save all the server URLs required, but I couldn't access that INI file whenever I am going to access INI file It will show me this error,

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\default.ini'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path)
   at DARDMeatInspection.services.QABMeatInspectionService.ReadINI() in D:\DARD\trunk\server\DARDMeatInspection\DARDMeatInspection\services\QABMeatInspectionService.asmx.cs:line 116
   at DARDMeatInspection.services.QABMeatInspectionService.GetAllClassifiers() in D:\DARD\trunk\server\DARDMeatInspection\DARDMeatInspection\services\QABMeatInspectionService.asmx.cs:line 27
```

Also, is it possible to change content of INI file after deployment?
If I am wrong please correct me. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you store your configuration in your app.config/web.config file?

Then grab your values using

```
string test1 = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Test1"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but is it possible to change config file after deployment. Please guide me.

Comment: Yes you can change the config after deployment and without compilation

Comment: Also Is it possible to change config file manually without compiling the whole app. would you please guide me how to achieve this. Since I am new to .net environment

Comment: You can edit the config file directly and this doesn't require your app to be recompiled as noted above.

Comment: No worries, don't forget to mark my answer as the solution. Thanks and good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

The [App_Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx) may be a viable candidate, especially because

> The content of application folders, except for the App_Themes folder, is not served in response to Web requests, but it can be accessed from application code.